# Android AlertDialog Builder multiple EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog, builder

I am wanting to use Android AlertDialog.Builder to programatically structure the layout of a dialog. I have two EditText fields that I want to display, displayed vertically, one on top of another, but I can't get it to work. The following code just displays the second one, as if it is being displayed over the first one linearly instead of vertically.

```
final EditText inputOne = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
final EditText inputTwo = new EditText(MainActivity.this);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                );

AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
inputOne.setLayoutParams(lp);
inputOne.setLayoutParams(lp);

alertDialog.setView(inputOne);
alertDialog.setView(inputTwo);
```

Comment: you can add both the `edittexts` into one `linearlayout` and then `alertDialog.setView(linearlayout)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a parent Layout and add the the views and finally set the view to dialog like this way:

```
    LinearLayout parent = new LinearLayout(this);

    parent.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    parent.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    parent.addView(inputOne);
    parent.addView(inputTwo);

    alertDialog.setView(parent);
```